# Java: Experimenting with generics

Tags: java, generics

Lastly I experimenting with generics a little bit. I came up with this piece of code:

```
public class Test {

    static <T> void f(T x) {
        x = (T) (Integer) 1234;
        System.out.println(x);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        f("a");
        f(1);
        f('a');
        f(1.5);
        f(new LinkedList<String>());
        f(new HashMap<String, String>());
    }
}
```

I ran this and got this output:

```
1234
1234
1234
1234
1234
1234
```

with no exceptions! How is it possible?

Comment: Be careful -- you're straying dangerously close to asking: "Why don't generics work like C++ templates?"

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It's because of [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) (a lot has been written about this, just google for this term). After compiling `f` to byte code the method might look like this:

```
static void f(Object x) {
    x = (Object) (Integer) 1234;
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

So `System.out.println` will just call the `toString` method on object `x` - and in your case it is [`Integer.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString%28%29).

Comment: thats an awesome answer :)

Answer (score 4):

Because of Type Erasure. From [Oracle's documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html):

> Generics were introduced to the Java language to provide tighter type
>   checks at compile time and to support generic programming. To
>   implement generics, the Java compiler applies type erasure to:
>
> - Replace all type parameters in generic types with their bounds or
>     Object if the type parameters are unbounded. The produced bytecode,
>     therefore, contains only ordinary classes, interfaces, and methods.
> - Insert type casts if necessary to preserve type safety.
> - Generate bridge methods to preserve polymorphism in extended generic types.
>
> Type erasure ensures that no new classes are created for parameterized
>   types; consequently, generics incur no runtime overhead.

Comment: When you copy the words of an external resource, always make sure you properly quote and link the original wording.